# How can I understand backbone syntax

Tags: javascript, css, backbone.js

I am learning `backbone.js`. I found the following code from backbone.js documentation.

```
 //cretaing class name as Sidebar with extends Backbone.Model class  
 var Sidebar = Backbone.Model.extend({
                promptColor:function() {
                    var cssColor = prompt("Please enter a CSS color:");
                    this.set({color1: cssColor});
                }
        });
  //cretaing object for Sidebar class
        var sidebarObject = new Sidebar();
  //following statement not understand
        sidebarObject.on("change:color1", function(model, color23) {
            $('#body1').css({background: color23})
        });
```

What I understand :

whenever attribute `color1` will change automatically model('Slidebar') triggers `sidebarObject.on()`.

What I didn't understand :

1. we are passing 2 arguments names are `model,color23` to second argument of the `sidebarObject.on()`. I didn't understand anything about that arguments.

2.As per my understanding model is `Sidebar` in my example.Is it right.

can anyone help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your second assumption is correct, in the above example Sidebar is the Model.

There are 2 parameters being passed to the callback function:

1. the model on which the event initially occurred
2. the value being passed alongside with the event

Note that the `sidebarObject` listens only to 'color' change events. Such event is generated when you  change that particular attribute of the model:

```
this.set({color1: cssColor});
```

Now, if you change the listener to:

```
sidebarObject.on("change:taste", function(model, color23) {
    $('#body1').css({background: color23})
});
```

it won't be fire anymore when `this.set({color: cssColor});` is called, because it listens to 'taste' change:

```
this.set({taste: 'good'});
```

I've separated the above example into a fiddle so you can play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/CtzsR/1/

If you are new to this whole thing http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-model/ is a site worth looking at.

I hope now it's clearer.

Comment: According to your point `1.the model on which the event initially occurred`, can I pass `Sidebar` as a argument instead of `model`.Also explain  me with simple example,If it listens with more attributes like  `sidebarObject.on("change:taste change:color1", function(model, color23,color24) {
    $('#body1').css({background: color23});
    alert("color24");
});`

Comment: those arguments you see in the callback function are passed by Backbone, you can rename them but Backbone will still pass the model at the first place and the event attribute at the second place. Yes, Backbone can listen to multiple attribute change events. I suggest you playing around that fiddle. I also modified it to represent listening on multiple attributes: http://jsfiddle.net/CtzsR/2/

Comment: what I posted code is working fine fine If I place in `.html` file. These same code I placed in separate `.js` file. and imported that file into my `.html` file here it's not working. Why can I add any extra code.

Comment: your environment is unknown to me but I'm sure that the problem has nothing to do with Backbone.